# Rule of thumb for complexity of 3d Kriging (with pykrige)

Tags: python, kriging

I've been using pykrige for some data interpolation. It's great and works well in 2d. I recently tried the 3D version though, and it takes forever to run (> a day before I killed it), just for roughly a 10x10x20 point fit.

I'm not sure if this is to be expected or not, does anyone know how I should expect the run time to scale as a function of the number of fit points? Just not sure if I should leave it to run for a week or if it would need much longer and I'll be wasting my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian here from the [GeoStat-Framework](https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework).

PyKrige will change in the future to depend more on the implementations of [GSTools](https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework/GSTools). If you have 10x10x20 input points, it should only take seconds with the routines there. With GStools v1.3 (that will be released this month), you can do something like:

```py
import gstools as gs

x, y, z = [...]   # your data coordinates
cond_val = [...]  # your data array

krige = gs.krige.Ordinary(
    model=gs.Spherical(dim=3),
    cond_pos=[x,y,z],
    cond_val=cond_val,
    fit_variogram=True,
)
# interpolate data on an output grid
field = krige(pos=output_grid)
```

For further questions you could use the Github Discussions Forum: https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework/GSTools/discussions

Hope this helps!
Sebastian

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.typing'`

I keep getting this error

Comment: That's unrelated to the problem and is most likely caused by another library. Try `pip install -U numpy`.